# Perl Directory Finder doesn't work?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, if-statement, directory

I have a script to find Directories and .tar.gz Files.  For whatever reason (that's what I'm hoping you can help me with) my

```
if ( -d $file )
```

doesn't return that it's a directory!!!

My Script:

```
# specify the directory where you want to start the search
my $directory = $ARGV[0];
my $directoryCount = 0;

# Calling the Subroutine, which searches the File
readDirectory($directory);

sub readDirectory
{
    my $directory = shift;
    my $searchfile = shift;
        my @directories;
        my $tarOuput;

    # a little bit output, in which directory the script
    # is searching at the moment (the following line is not necessary)
    print "Searching in $directory\n\n";

    # Open and close the directory
    opendir(DIR, $directory) or die("ERROR: Couldn't open specified directory $!");
    my @files = readdir DIR;
    closedir DIR;

    shift(@files);
    shift(@files);

    print "------------------------------------------------------------------------    \n\n";

    foreach my $currentFile (@files)
    {
        print "Current File:", $currentFile, "\n\n";
        if ( -d $currentFile )  #THIS DOESN'T WORK?!?!?!?!?
        {
                        print "Directory: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";
                        #push (@directories, $currentFile);
                        #print "Found new directory:     $directories[$directoryCount]\n\nCurrent number = $directoryCount\n\n";
                        #$directoryCount++;
                        #print "Directories: ", @directories, "\n\n";
                        #next;
                        # The Subroutine is calling hisself with the new parameters
                        #readDirectory($currentFile); #recursive call through sub-directories
        }

        elsif ( $currentFile =~ /\.tar.gz$/i || $currentFile =~ /\.tar$/i)
        {
                        print "File: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";
                        my $tarOutput = `tar -tvzf $currentFile`;
                        print $tarOutput, "\n";
        }

        print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------    \n\n";
    }
}
```

The print statement that will print the $currentFile if it's a directory never prints...

Output:

```
Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File:Dir1

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File:file

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File:configs.tar.gz

File: configs.tar.gz

tar (child): configs.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File:adstatlog.299

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File:adstatlog.tgz

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've done the exact same thing with a super simple script in the same directory and it works...But nope, not here.  I don't understand what's wrong...?

Help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what looks wrong. See `diff` below

```
--- yours.pl    
+++ mine.pl 

     # Open and close the directory
     opendir(DIR, $directory) or die("ERROR: Couldn't open specified directory $!");
-    my @files = readdir DIR;
+    my @files = grep { $_ !~ /^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir DIR;
     closedir DIR;

-    shift(@files);
-    shift(@files);

     foreach my $currentFile (@files)
     {
+        my $fullPath = "$directory/$currentFile";
         print "Current File:", $currentFile, "\n\n";
-        if ( -d $currentFile )  #THIS DOESN'T WORK?!?!?!?!?
+        if ( -d $fullPath )  #THIS DOESN'T WORK?!?!?!?!?
         {
             print "Directory: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";
             #push (@directories, $currentFile);
             #print "Directories: ", @directories, "\n\n";
             #next;
             # The Subroutine is calling hisself with the new parameters
-            #readDirectory($currentFile); #recursive call through sub-directories
+            readDirectory($fullPath); #recursive call through sub-directories
         }
```

I'm guessing that the double `shift` is meaning to shift off "." and "..", which is incorrect. That might work if you did `sort @files`, but would still be a bad way to do it. See [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

Next problem is that `$currentFile` needs to be the full path here. Otherwise it's looking for `$currentFile` in the current working directory

Comment: Yes that's what the Shifts were for.  Thank you for that!

Comment: @user2340116 is this now clear? Or are you having an issue reading this `diff` output?

Comment: @user2340116 NP, note the `shift`ing part as well. That was most likely removing two files you didn't intend to lose.

Comment: Actually it was removing the "." and ".." just like you said.  But yes, I understand that that is not the way to do it as I'm sure situations will arise where they aren't the first 2 getting put int he array.  Your grep line removed those though, right?

Comment: @user2340116 yes, the `grep` is the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if ( -d $directory.'/'.$currentFile )
```